# How to get current page id in Lightning controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using `force:hasRecordId` and   `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />`..to get the ID to Controller.

## Component:

```
<aura:component controller="dcontroller" implements='force:hasRecordId'>

    <link href="assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

    <ui:inputSelect class="slds-col slds-media slds-media--center" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic"/>
</aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
public class dcontroller {


    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getpickval(ID accId) {
        List<String> options = new List<String>();

        List<Contact> contactResult = [Select Name from Contact where AccountID =:accId];
        options.add('Contact ('+ contactResult.size() + ')');
        for (Contact f: contactResult) {
            options.add(f.Name);
        }       
        return options;
    }
}
```

## Helper.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getpickval");
action.setParams({
            "accId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        var inputsel = component.find("InputSelectDynamic");
        var opts=[];
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
                opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
            }
            inputsel.set("v.options", opts);

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        }
})
```

## Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
<div id="lightning" />
    <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:dApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:dComp",
                {},
                "InputSelectDynamic",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("Component created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                });
            });


    </script>
    <div id="InputSelectDynamic"></div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You have mentioned Lead as your standard controller; whilst you are sending the account Id to the controller. May be this is causing the issue?

Comment: No Shailesh..its not the issue

Answer (score 3):

The value of the 'recordId' attribute is not being set anywhere in the process. You might want pass the value of 'record Id' from the *script* part of visual force page

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:dApp", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:dComp",
        { recordId : "PassThe RecordId from Here"},
        "InputSelectDynamic",
        function(cmp) {
            console.log("Component created!");
            console.log(cmp);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please confirm if this worked

Comment: No Gopal..it is giving "Something has gone wrong. cmp is not defined. Please try again." message..

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<apex:includeLightning />
```

instead of:

```
 <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
```

---

See [Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm):

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lcvfTest", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("ui:button",
          { label : "Press Me!" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```