# lightning Component called via visualforce page using quick action doesnt render properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning component that i want to call from visualforce page. Earlier i posted a question about that [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136712/how-to-update-the-record-in-lightning-components-when-calling-from-visualforce-p). now I figured out how to make it work. But I ran into another problem when component dynamically loaded, it doesn't render properly. there is some white space. as shown in the image.

I'm using an iOS device and Salesforce1 app. I couldn't figure out what i'm doing wrong here. I really appreciate you taking your time to look at this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused because i missed to add a reference to scope as mentioned in this [trail head section](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-3).

I downloaded the SLDS from the tool provided by salesforce with the custom scope name and referenced this scope in the component. that fixed the problem.